# Show that the tangent to $y = x^{1/3}$ at $T(-1,-1)$ meets the curve again at $(8,2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Show that the tangent to $y = x^{1/3}$ at $T(-1,-1)$ meets the curve again at $(8,2)$.

I'm a new student to calculus, so sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: The fist question you must address is: What is the equation of the tangent line? Can you get this equation?

Comment: i tried differentiating it, and got y'=1/3x^-2/3. from here, I don't understand where I need to sub in T

Comment: Edit your question to include this. The fact that $T(-1,-1)$ is a point of the curve means that $-1=(-1)^{1/3}$. Therefore you want to find the equation of the curve at the point of the graph where $x=-1$.

Comment: The slope of the tangent line at the point $T(-1, -1)$ is equal to the derivative at $x = -1$.  That gives you a point and a slope for the tangent line, from which you can find its equation.